# How to decode a aes-128-ecb where the key has random length?

Tags: node.js, aes

I'm trying to decode a code using nodejs and crypto. I tried to decode it using [this website](http://tool.chacuo.net/cryptaes) to get the result that I want. But I think I'm buffering the key the wrong way. How can I decode where the key is vague?

```
const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-128-ecb", Buffer.from('4d52c7125cdd4e55868e190e0ec1c846', 'hex'), null);
const decryptedSecret = decipher.update('8E874DE6CE510690F8E2866FF5C8EA18A6B7CEF9DD4048C4EF6C7FFE678C6FD3', 'hex', 'hex') + decipher.final("hex");
console.log("final: ", decryptedSecret);
```

My expected result per the [website](http://tool.chacuo.net/cryptaes) is `VeHo8t9C1DNxLsaU`. I also tried to reverse encode it but still didnt get any result wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is AES-256-ECB with PKCS7 padding, the key `4d52...c846` is to be UTF-8 encoded, as output encoding UTF-8 is to be applied:

```js
const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-ecb', Buffer.from('4d52c7125cdd4e55868e190e0ec1c846', 'utf8'), null);
const decryptedSecret = decipher.update('8E874DE6CE510690F8E2866FF5C8EA18A6B7CEF9DD4048C4EF6C7FFE678C6FD3', 'hex', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8');
console.log("final: ", decryptedSecret); // final:  VeHo8t9C1DNxLsaU
```

Comment: Cool this works but from the docs that I'm following it says that it was encrypted with aes-128-ecb with PKCS7 padding. Is it okay to change to 256? When I also used the website with 128bit I got the expected result.

Comment: @goaty - The ciphertext was clearly generated with AES-256-ECB, as evidenced by the successful decryption. Presumably, the website specifies the _block size_ (which is 128 bits for AES). The number in AES-256-ECB, on the other hand, specifies the _key size_ in bits.